# Remove all leading zeroes in a string for first column only

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed

I have a pipe delimited file and in order to join it with a corresponding file I need to remove the leading zeroes from the first column but not from any other columns in the file.

The structure looks like this:

```
GA.01.02.070|GLS Add. GA 1/2/70|Wohl&#58; Wagon d. Kelder&#228;ra. ||||||
GA.01.02.071|GLS Add. GA 1/2/71|Ts&#228; der Kelderära. Ro&#223;lau, 1935. ||||||
GA.01.02.072|GLS Add. GA 1/2/72|R&#243;mni der Kelder&#228;ra. ||||||
GA.01.02.073|GLS Add. GA 1/2/73|Wagen des Mets. Ro&#223;lau&#x0002F; 1934. ||||||
GA.01.02.074|GLS Add. GA 1/2/74|Kastanja Ansin. ||||||
GA.01.02.075|GLS Add. GA 1/2/75|Raupa Ansin. ||||||
```

and my desired output would be:

```
GA.1.2.70|GLS Add. GA 1/2/70|Wohl&#58; Wagon d. Kelder&#228;ra. ||||||
GA.1.2.71|GLS Add. GA 1/2/71|Ts&#228; der Kelderära. Ro&#223;lau, 1935. ||||||
GA.1.2.72|GLS Add. GA 1/2/72|R&#243;mni der Kelder&#228;ra. ||||||
GA.1.2.73|GLS Add. GA 1/2/73|Wagen des Mets. Ro&#223;lau&#x0002F; 1934. ||||||
GA.1.2.74|GLS Add. GA 1/2/74|Kastanja Ansin. ||||||
GA.1.2.75|GLS Add. GA 1/2/75|Raupa Ansin. ||||||
```

I've been able to find ways of using sed to remove the first leading zero or all zeroes but I haven't found a way to remove just the leading zeroes before the first pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sed` isn’t a strict requirement, here’s an AWK script which will do the trick:

```
awk -F\| 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { gsub("\\.0+", ".", $1); print }'
```

This splits records on `|`, using that on output too; for each record, it replaces `.` followed by one or more `0` by `.` in the first field, then outputs the full record.

Comment: to add them back again would it be a case of: awk -F\| 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { gsub("\\(.[1-9]+", ".0", $1); print  }' ../out/alt.csv ?