# Add leading zeroes to first column

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, sed

I'm looking to add four leading zeroes to the first column of a csv file so this:

```
EADUnitID,irn,EADPhysicalTechnical,AdmPublishWebNoPassword,AdmPublishWebPassword,EADUnitTitle,EADBiographyOrHistory,EADScopeAndContent,EADArrangement,EADAcquisitionInformationRef.SummaryData,EADRelatedMaterial,BibBibliographyRef_tab.SummaryData
ga.1.2.6,52144,GLS Add. GA 1/2/6,Yes,Yes,Dzöfi. ,,,,,,
ga.1.2.7,52145,GLS Add. GA 1/2/7,Yes,Yes,Dzöfi. ,,,,,,
ga.1.2.8,52146,GLS Add. GA 1/2/8,Yes,Yes,Two young girls. ,,,,,,
ga.1.2.9,52147,GLS Add. GA 1/2/9,Yes,Yes,J. Blum. ,,,,,,
ga.1.2.10,52148,GLS Add. GA 1/2/10,Yes,Yes,TsïGA.0 ,,,,,,
ga.1.2.11,52149,GLS Add. GA 1/2/11,Yes,Yes,Wupa. ,,,,,,
ga.1.2.12,52150,GLS Add. GA 1/2/12,Yes,Yes,Tochter des Bälo Laubinger. Stamm: Lowära, Pferdezigeuner. ,,,,,,
...<snip>...
ga.1.2.311,52449,GLS Add. GA 1/2/311,Yes,Yes,Beinrode 1962. Zu dunkel! ,,,,,,
ga.1.2.312,52450,GLS Add. GA 1/2/312,Yes,Yes,Bienrode 1962. Zu dunkel! ,,,,,,
ga.1.2.313,52451,GLS Add. GA 1/2/313,Yes,Yes,Bienrode 1962. Zu dunkel! ,,,,,,
ga.1.2.314,52452,GLS Add. GA 1/2/314,Yes,Yes,Lowara und Sintitsa! FrÜhjahr Bienrode 1962. ,,,,,,
ga.1.2.315,52453,GLS Add. GA 1/2/315,Yes,Yes,Madamenweg Walódza und Peabaí März 1962. Als ich die Familie photographierte, entbläßte plötzlich die Frau ihre Brust Vielleicht hätte ich nun nicht knipsen dÜrfen. Aber anderseits war das Erleben interessant. Offenbar meint die Frau mit Liege ansolchen Bildern. Georg Althaus. ,,,,,,
ga.1.2.316,52454,GLS Add. GA 1/2/316,Yes,Yes,Dzöfi. Dzöfi u. ihre schwester Rúpa gehören zur Gruppe der ungarischen Zig., mithin zu den Romzig. Sie sind also Lòwära, Pferdezig. ,,,,,,
ga.1.2.319ca,52455,GLS Add. GA 1/2/317-327,Yes,Yes,Closed to Access ,,,,,,
ga.2,52456,GLS Add. GA 2,Yes,Yes,Hanns Weltzel papers. ,,,,,,
```

Would look like this:

```
EADUnitID,irn,EADPhysicalTechnical,AdmPublishWebNoPassword,AdmPublishWebPassword,EADUnitTitle,EADBiographyOrHistory,EADScopeAndContent,EADArrangement,EADAcquisitionInformationRef.SummaryData,EADRelatedMaterial,BibBibliographyRef_tab.SummaryData
ga.00001.00002.00006,52144,GLS Add. GA 1/2/6,Yes,Yes,Dzöfi. ,,,,,,
ga.00001.00002.00007,52145,GLS Add. GA 1/2/7,Yes,Yes,Dzöfi. ,,,,,,
ga.00001.00002.00008,52146,GLS Add. GA 1/2/8,Yes,Yes,Two young girls. ,,,,,,
ga.00001.00002.00009,52147,GLS Add. GA 1/2/9,Yes,Yes,J. Blum. ,,,,,,
ga.00001.00002.00010,52148,GLS Add. GA 1/2/10,Yes,Yes,TsïGA.0 ,,,,,,
ga.00001.00002.00011,52149,GLS Add. GA 1/2/11,Yes,Yes,Wupa. ,,,,,,
ga.00001.00002.00012,52150,GLS Add. GA 1/2/12,Yes,Yes,Tochter des Bälo Laubinger. Stamm: Lowära, Pferdezigeuner. ,,,,,,
...<snip>...
ga.00001.00002.00311,52449,GLS Add. GA 1/2/311,Yes,Yes,Beinrode 1962. Zu dunkel! ,,,,,,
ga.00001.00002.00312,52450,GLS Add. GA 1/2/312,Yes,Yes,Bienrode 1962. Zu dunkel! ,,,,,,
ga.00001.00002.00313,52451,GLS Add. GA 1/2/313,Yes,Yes,Bienrode 1962. Zu dunkel! ,,,,,,
ga.00001.00002.00314,52452,GLS Add. GA 1/2/314,Yes,Yes,Lowara und Sintitsa! FrÜhjahr Bienrode 1962. ,,,,,,
ga.00001.00002.00315,52453,GLS Add. GA 1/2/315,Yes,Yes,Madamenweg Walódza und Peabaí März 1962. Als ich die Familie photographierte, entbläßte plötzlich die Frau ihre Brust Vielleicht hätte ich nun nicht knipsen dÜrfen. Aber anderseits war das Erleben interessant. Offenbar meint die Frau mit Liege ansolchen Bildern. Georg Althaus. ,,,,,,
ga.00001.00002.00316,52454,GLS Add. GA 1/2/316,Yes,Yes,Dzöfi. Dzöfi u. ihre schwester Rúpa gehören zur Gruppe der ungarischen Zig., mithin zu den Romzig. Sie sind also Lòwära, Pferdezig. ,,,,,,
ga.00001.00002.00319ca,52455,GLS Add. GA 1/2/317-327,Yes,Yes,Closed to Access ,,,,,,
ga.00002,52456,GLS Add. GA 2,Yes,Yes,Hanns Weltzel papers. ,,,,,,
```

I've tried looking at gsub, gensub and printf but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed.

Comment: [You and zeroes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473176/remove-all-leading-zeroes-in-a-string-for-first-column-only) have a tumultuous relationship!

Comment: To be specific here, how many zeroes are you adding? Padding to 5, or just always adding 4?

Comment: @JeffSchaller it's a love/hate kind of thing. First I can't stand them, and then I want them back.

Comment: @JeffSchaller padding to 5 I think is fairly safe. They represent records belonging to collections and are used to construct hierarchy trees and whilst there are over 100k records, none of the individual collections go over 5 digits.

Comment: It makes it slightly trickier that `319ca` is not an integer...

Comment: @Kusalananda i thought that might be the case. I'm open to changing the files so that in these cases any text is moved behind a separate period e.g. ga.00001.00002.00319.ca but I might need some guidance in how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, slightly trickier. Try

```
awk -F, '
        {n=split ($1, T, "\.")
         $1 = DL = ""
         for (i=1; i<=n; i++)   {S[i] = T[i] + 0
                                 gsub (/[0-9]/, "", T[i])
                                 $1 = $1 DL (S[i]?sprintf ("%05d", S[i]):"") T[i]
                                 DL = "."
                                }
        }
1
' OFS=, file
```

It splits the first field on `.` into array `T`, then loops across `T`, puts the respective element's starting digits into array `S` (making use of `awk`s feature to use only a string's leading digits for arithmetics), removes the leading digits (only!) from `T`, and rebuilds the `$1` field.

Comment: accepted as you answered first. Thanks for the explanation too, I probably hack this around to do something badly in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is an option

```
perl -F, -pe '$_ = join ",", @F if $F[0] =~ s/(\d+)/sprintf "%05d", $1/ge' file
```

Comment: I still have nightmares about writing a SOAP client in Perl. Are you passing sprintf to the Perl substitute string? I didn't even consider that as a possibility, that is genius.

Comment: @joesch basically, yes - the `e` regex modifier says *"evaluate the right-hand side as an expression"* . See for example [perlre: Modifiers](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers).